Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements | Coretex IBRIGHT-API
I keep getting the error:

Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.

I get this whenever I try to post a new circle geofence.

I would expect that this would successfully create a new geofence.
I don't have access to this API.

What do you mean by "I don't have access to this API."? You mean you don't have access to the documentation? Or you don't have an API key/token? Or something else?

I don't have access to the api code. I have an access token + documentation

Hard to say since it appears to be a closed source/paid API. I think you should put in a ticket with iBright support. This is an unusual Body result for any API call... either there's a bug on their side which you can't fix, or you're missing/have some incorrect parameters. Unfortunately without access to the documentation we can't say which.
